# How to find the referers [sic] for a suddenly popular question?

Tags: discussion

A two-year-old answer of mine suddenly got 7 upvotes today, almost doubling its score. Is there a way I can find the HTTP referers [sic] for this Question or Answer so I can find out where the sudden popularity is coming from?

[Can other people on an encrypted Wi-Fi AP see what you're doing?](https://superuser.com/questions/156869/can-other-people-on-an-encrypted-wi-fi-ap-see-what-youre-doing/156969#156969)

...but rather than just knowing the answer this time, I'd like to know how to find out for myself in the future.  I tried a few Google "link:" searches for the long and short versions of both the Question and my specific Answer links, but didn't turn up anything external, just a few links from the FAQs for a couple tags.

Comment: You just referred me :P

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (even if you are a mod).

You might get lucky and see if some user gets an announcer/booster badge for your question, but that will get you a user (and therefore a link) and not its location.

You could try:

- looking up its URL in a search engine and see if it's linked on a page out there in the wilderness
- scan Twitterverse for possible hints or mentions
- reddit via reddit.com/domain/superuser.com/?sort=new

Comment: Mods can see _some_ analytics, but not by specific question.

Comment: @random, thanks.